# Operator used tempdb to spill.... with variables but not literals

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need help understanding this SQL Server behavior

I have a fairly basic query like

```
select x, y, sum(z) 
from table 
where date between @start and @end
group by x, y
```

There's a large number of rows (filter condition retrieves 6 million rows out of 16 million total)

The thing I don't understand is: this query is slow and I get a warning about spilling to tempdb.  But if I change it and simply replace `@start` and `@end` with the same dates directly, it's much faster and there's no warning about tempdb spillage.

My guess is that the tempdb spill is because of cardinality estimates.

It appears that when I'm using variables, the statistics are way off.  It's estimating about 1.45 million rows instead of 6 million.

When I use literals, the estimates are almost exactly correct.

How can I get correct estimates, and avoid tempdb spill, when using variables?

Comment: Are your statistics up to date?

Comment: Good read: http://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/tempdb-spills/

Comment: I think stats are OK based on seeing correct estimates with literals.  issue seems to be my variable values aren't being used for estimates.

Comment: What happens if you do `where date >= @start and date <= @end`?

Comment: same behavior with between vs. inequality operators

Comment: Are `@start` and `@end` variables or parameters?  I ask because this sounds like a parameter-sniffing problem.  If they are parameters, then try assigning them into variables and using the variables instead.  If that also fixes the problem, then it's definitely parameter sniffing.

Comment: See my own answer - they were local variables, and rather than sniffing, it was that the values weren't used at all in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tempdb spill was because of estimates, which weren't right because I was using local variables.

If I changed the local variables to parameterized SQL with `sp_executesql`, the estimates became correct, and the tempdb spill went away.

However, even with the tempdb spill addressed, parameterized SQL is *still* slower than using literals, and I created a new question for that separate issue.

[SQL Server 2014 performance - parameterized SQL vs. literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32017484/sql-server-2014-performance-parameterized-sql-vs-literals?noredirect=1#comment51937583_32017484)

Comment: So wrapping it up in sp_executesql was your fix?  Curious, wonder if plan caching played a factor here.  I'd be curious what someone like Gordon Linoff says here.  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think plan caching was a factor, because I hadn't run the same query with any *other* values.

Comment: more likely that using a local variables are "special" - found this link http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/03/local-variable-vs-stored-procedure/

Answer (score 3):

> The tempdb spill was because of estimates, which weren't right because
>   I was using local variables.

**Some stuff on *why* they were wrong because of the local variables:**

SQL Server cardinality estimation can use two types of statistics to guess how many rows will get through a predicate filter:

1. Statistics about the column on average using the *density vector*, and
2. Statistics about particular values for that column using the *histogram*

If you're not familiar with statistics objects and their density vectors / histograms, read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx).

When a literal is used, the cardinality estimator can search for that literal in the histogram (the second type of statistics). When a parameter is used, its value is not evaluated until after cardinality estimation, so the CE has to use column averages in the density vector (the first type of statistics).

In general, you'll get better estimations using literals because the statistics in the histogram are tailored to the value of the literal, rather than being averaged over the whole column.

---

**Example**

**Case 1: Literal**

I'm running the following query on the [AdventureWorks2012_Data](https://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/releases/view/55330) database:

```
SELECT *
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE UnitPriceDiscount = 0
```

We've got a literal, so the CE will look for the value `0` in the UnitPriceDiscount histogram to figure out how many rows will be returned.

I've [run debugging output to see which statistics object is being used](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/09/21/how-to-find-the-statistics-used-to-compile-an-execution-plan.aspx) and [queried that object to see its contents](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174384.aspx), and here's the histogram:

[image: UnitPriceDiscount statistics object histogram]

The value `0` is a RANGE_HI_KEY, so the estimated number of rows with that value is its EQ_ROWS column - in this case 117996.9.

Now let's look at the execution plan for the query:

[image: Execution plan with literal]

The 'Filter' step is getting rid of all rows that don't match the predicate, so the 'Estimated Number of Rows' section of its properties has the result of the cardinality estimation:

[image]

That's the value we saw in the histogram, rounded.

**Case 2: Parameter**

Now we'll try with a parameter:

```
DECLARE @temp int = 0

SELECT *
FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
WHERE UnitPriceDiscount = @temp
```

The cardinality estimator doesn't have a literal to search for in the histogram, so it has to use the overall density of the column from the density vector:

[image]

This number is:

```
1 / the number of distinct values in the UnitPriceDiscount column
```

So if you multiply that by the number of rows in the table, you get the average number of rows per value in this column. There are 121317 rows in Sales.SalesOrderDetail, so the calculation is:

```
121317 * 0.1111111 = 13479.6653187
```

The execution plan:

[image: Execution plan with parameter]

The properties of the filter:

[image: Filter properties with parameter]

So the new estimation is coming from the *density vector, not the histogram*.

Let me know if you have a look at the stats object and it doesn't add up as above.