# SQL Server 2014 performance - parameterized SQL vs. literals

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple query like

```
select count(distinct key) 
from table 
where date between '2014-01-01' and '2014-12-31'
```

It's fast (about 1 second), but becomes much slower (about 4 seconds) when I try to parameterize it within `sp_executesql`:

```
exec sp_executesql 
     N'select count(distinct key) from table where date between @start and @end', 
     N'@start date, @end date',
     @start = '2014-01-01', @end='2014-12-31'
```

Why the difference in performance?

**UPDATE** The plan difference appears to be because of type conversion.  When I change the parameter types to N'@start datetime, @end datetime', to match the columns exactly, the discrepancy disappears, and the plans for parameters vs. constants are practically identical (same costs, etc.)  (Facepalm.)

I'll accept an answer that explains why the type conversion results in such a dramatic plan difference rather than just converting the parameters up front and proceeding as usual.

**END UPDATE**

The plans are very similar - same index, same estimated cardinalities, same row counts, and same I/O - although the CPU cost estimates in the parameterized version are higher.

Specific discrepancies:

- The same Index Seek appears in both plans, but it is parallel in the (fast) version with literals, and NOT parallel in the (slow) version with parameters.  The non-parallel one has higher CPU estimate.
- The version with parameters has an Nested Loop join connecting the index scan with some logic around parameters.  This appears to add some CPU overhead of its own (CPU estimate = 7.6 on the nested loop).
- Both versions have "Parallelism" as a child of the Hash Match; in the parameterized version it is Distribute Streams (CPU estimate = 16.5) but in the literal version it is Repartition Streams (CPU estimate = 8.3)

How can I get the parameterized version to perform similarly as the version with literals?

All I could find in my research about performance of parameterized queries has to do with estimates -- either plans cached with different parameter values, or local variables  being treated as unknowns.  Neither is a factor here; my estimates are correct.

Comment: can you paste the execution plan xml?

Comment: Dupe post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32015882/operator-used-tempdb-to-spill-with-variables-but-not-literals

Comment: slightly different question.  I fixed the original estimates problem and tempdb spill, but there's still a performance discrepancy between literals and parameterized SQL

Comment: I see that, my apologies.

Comment: What's the question? This is a typical parameterization issue. Have you researched this? Why can't you use the usual solutions?

Comment: here's a hint - the plan is the same, but what about the estimate/cost?  you should see differences there.

Comment: Not seeing any difference in my AdventureWorks2014. Here's the query I used: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT ProductID) FROM Production.WorkOrder WHERE StartDate BETWEEN '2014-01-01' AND '2014-12-31'`

Comment: "How can I get the parameterized version to perform similarly as the version with literals?": Use [`OPTION(RECOMPILE)`](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html) and execution plan of parameterized query should become the same as version with literals.

Answer (score 3):

> Why the difference in performance?

Because you have two different queries and they have two different execution plans (even though they are similar).

Why do you have two different plans?

There is a great detailed article by Erland Sommarskog [Slow in the Application, Fast in SSMS? Understanding Performance Mysteries](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html), where he explains how query optimizer works. The key points applicable to your example are:

> - A constant is a constant, and when a query includes a constant, SQL Server can use the value of the constant with full trust, and even
>     take such shortcuts to not access a table at all, if it can infer from
>     constraints that no rows will be returned.
> - For a parameter, SQL Server does not know the run-time value, but it "sniffs" the input value when compiling the query.
> - For a local variable, SQL Server has no idea at all of the run-time value, and applies standard assumptions. (Which the assumptions are
>     depends on the operator  and what can be deduced from the presence of
>     unique indexes.)
>
> And there is a corollary of this: if you take out a query from a
>   stored procedure and replace variables and parameters with constants,
>   you now have quite a different query.

As shown in the article quick answer to:

> How can I get the parameterized version to perform similarly as the
>   version with literals?

is to use [`OPTION(RECOMPILE) / OPTIMIZE FOR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx).

**RECOMPILE**

> Instructs the SQL Server Database Engine to discard the plan generated
>   for the query after it executes, forcing the query optimizer to
>   recompile a query plan the next time the same query is executed.
>   Without specifying RECOMPILE, the Database Engine caches query plans
>   and reuses them. When compiling query plans, the RECOMPILE query hint
>   *uses the current values of any local **variables** in the query and, if
>   the query is inside a stored procedure, the current values passed to
>   any **parameters***.

So, option `RECOMPILE` behaves as if query had literal values instead of parameters.

**OPTIMIZE FOR**

> Instructs the query optimizer to use a particular value for a local
>   variable when the query is compiled and optimized. The value is used
>   only during query optimization, and not during query execution.

Comment: Thanks, this is a helpful resource.  I discovered the difference between local variables and parameters already, which was causing a problem with cardinality estimates.  Using a query compiled with different parameters could be an issue too.  In my case here, neither is the issue.

Comment: I think that answer to "How can I get the parameterized version to perform similarly as the version with literals?" is: use `OPTION(RECOMPILE)`. When you use this option with parameters, do you get the same plan and performance as with literals?